# The package mysql-server-5.7 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: mysql, linux

My MySql is not working. When I want to reinstall MySql on linux server the I it shows following message.

```
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client --fix-broken
```

message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package mysql-server-5.7 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Comment: This might be better for Unix & Linux stack exchange site, rather than Stack Overflow which is for programming questions.

Comment: Do you get the same error with apt-get update?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `sudo dpkg --remove --force-all mysql-server-5.7`

If that doesn't work,

```
sudo vim /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

You can do this with any text editor.

After you open that find the section about mysql-server-5.7. Delete the section with the information pertaining to it and save the file. Make sure you do a backup of the status file before you do this.

Reinstall your package using `apt-get install`

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this question as answered.

Comment: You are my hero :)
Finally after a year of suffering

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the installation was messed up and I had to remove the requirement with `dpkg`

I received a message like:

```
E: The package <package-name> needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I was able to resolve like this:

1. Query faulty packages using `dkpg`

```
$ dpkg -C

The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
that depend on them) to function properly:
 <package-name>         (no description available)

The following packages are missing the list control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
 <package-name>         (no description available)

The following packages are missing the md5sums control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
 <package-name>         (no description available)
```

2. force-remove install requirement for each listed package

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <package-name>
```

Comment: So many highly rated answers did not work. This simple solution worked for me!